How many fields $M$ are there with $\mathbb{Q} < M < L$ and $[M : \mathbb{Q}] = 4?$
Here  $L= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3, \sqrt 5)$
How many fields $M$ are there with $\mathbb{Q} < M < L$ and $[M : \mathbb{Q}] = 4?$
My attempt: Here $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=[L:M][M:\mathbb{Q}]$
If  a  field $M$ with $\mathbb{Q} < M < L$ corresponds to a  subgroups $H \le Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$
we have
$|H|=[L:M]=2$
I am unable to proceed after that

Hi, can you define what are $M$ and $L$ ? It is hard to answer your question without any context

@Shika I edited

You are looking for subgroup of order $2$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$. Those are exactly groups generated by elements of order $2$. Can you, by any chance, describe $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ ?

Three obvious examples for $M$ include $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$. Are there any others?

@GeoffreyTrang Okay, so only $3$ M are available

@Shika I think we need to find the intermediate field of degree  $4 ?$

@jasmine "Okay, so only 3 M are available" - My comment only says that the answer must be at least $3$. It is possible that it could be more than $3$.

You should definitely try to describe the Galois group - it's much easier to answer using that than enumerating the possibilities for $M$ and proving there are no others.

We can generalize the problem to the situation where $K = \mathbb{Q}$ and $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q}, \sqrt{r})$ where $p, q, r$ are any distinct prime numbers. Now there is an isomorphism $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q}, \sqrt{r}) / \mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^{3}$. You can show this by considering the automorphisms sending $\sqrt{p}$ to $-\sqrt{p}$ while fixing $\sqrt{q}$ and $\sqrt{r}$, and analogously the automorphisms sending $\sqrt{q}$ to $-\sqrt{q}$ and $\sqrt{r}$ to $-\sqrt{r}$. These automorphisms will generate $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q}, \sqrt{r}) / \mathbb{Q})$ and it is seen by the interchanging of signs that the Galois group is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $\{\pm 1\}^{3}$ and hence isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^{3}$.
As stated in the comments, determining the amount of fields $M$ such that $K < M < L$ and $[M : K] = 4$ boils down to determining the amount of subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^{3}$ of order 2. Each of these subgroups are generated by elements of order 2. From the structure of $(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z})^{3}$ it is clear that there are 7 elements of order 2, and hence there are 7 subgroups of order 2, and hence 7 of such fields $M$.
This is not part of the question, but the 7 fields $M$ such that $[M : K] = 4$ are: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q}), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{r}), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q}, \sqrt{r}), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{pq}, \sqrt{r}), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{pr}, \sqrt{q}), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{qr}, \sqrt{p}), \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{pq}, \sqrt{qr})$.

For the last field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{pq}, \sqrt{qr})$, it may be worth noting that a subfield of $L$ that contains any two of $\sqrt{pq}, \sqrt{qr}, \sqrt{pr}$ must also contain the third, as $\sqrt{pq}\sqrt{qr}=q\sqrt{pr}$.
